# spark hive get external partition file location

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I'm trying to get the **external** table file location of a partition calculated at run time. Simply alter table drop wouldn't work since it's external. The closest I can get is

```html
spark.sql(s"describe $tableName partition ($partitionBy=$partitionValue)")
```

But this would fail when partitionValue is of type timestamp and directly toString before calling the above function. Is there a way to use the same function where spark.write.saveastable() use to create the file path? or is there a way to get the location of the data by partition at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Try something

```
show table extended FROM $tableSchema like $tableName partition ($partitionBy=$partitionValue)
```

See more here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-ref-syntax-aux-show-table.html